# Always show one text in Bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Not changable text">
     <option>Mustard</option>
     <option>Ketchup</option>
     <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

So there are bootstrap-select(multiple).

Is it possible not to change title when user something check/select?

*Behaviour like in Bootstrap dropdown.*

Example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Without any JS :*

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/1/

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Not changable text" data-show-content data-count-selected-text="Not changable text" data-selected-text-format="count>0">
         <option data-content="">Mustard</option>
         <option data-content="">Ketchup</option>
         <option data-content="">Relish</option>
 </select>
```

### Update

*Sorry , my code was with not usefull attributes...*
Just add `data-count-selected-text="Not changable text" data-selected-text-format="count>0"`

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/re8tevoc/2/

**Code** :

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple title="Not changable text" data-count-selected-text="Not changable text" data-selected-text-format="count>0">
         <option>Mustard</option>
         <option>Ketchup</option>
         <option>Relish</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that putting *title* after every *option* tag:

```
<option title="something">Mustard</option>
<option title="something">Ketchup</option>
<option title="something">Relish</option>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aaach7sr/

Whatever option is checked the title of select bar would be "something".

Comment: Could you make jsfiddle for that? :-)

Comment: @phillip100 my example is for case when you can select only one option not multiple..

Comment: the question is about *multiple*, that's why I asked for jsfiddle example :-)